# when upgrading gradle to 7.4, jar task cannot run correctly

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jar, task

in my project with flavor, when upgrade gradle to version 7.4, the following task cannot generate jar file as expect, and I’ m sure the files for from('build/intermediates/javac/overseaRelease/classes') exist

```
task makeDependJar(type: Jar) {
    from('build/intermediates/javac/overseaRelease/classes')
    archiveFileName = 'depend.jar'
    exclude("android/", "BuildConfig.class")
    destinationDir = file("../output")
}
```

Looking forward your answers, thanks!

depend.jar exists in out/ dir